# Convert code from Common Lisp to Scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp, common-lisp, mit-scheme

I made a program in Common Lisp and I am trying to make it work in Scheme as well, but it is not working. I am new to Scheme and MIT/GNU Scheme. 
Here is the code in Common Lisp. It is working fine in Lispworks:

```
(defun removeAdjc (L) (cond ((null L) L)
      (t (cond ((equal (car L) (cadr L)) (removeAdjc (cdr L))) 
         (t (append (list (car L)) (removeAdjc (cdr L))))))))
```

Here is the code that I used for Scheme:

```
(define (removeAdjc L)
     (if (null? L) L
        (if (equal? (car L) (cadr L)) (removeAdjc (cdr L))
              (append (list (car L)) (removeAdjc (cdr L)))
           ) ))
```

This is what I get when trying it on MIT/GNU Scheme:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason of the error is that you check only the end of the list, with `(null? L)`, while you should check also if the list has one element (since you are doing `(cadr L)`). So a correct definition could be:

```
(define (removeAdjc L)
  (cond ((null? L) L)
        ((null? (cdr L)) L)
        ((equal? (car L) (cadr L)) (removeAdjc (cdr L)))
        (else (cons (car L) (removeAdjc (cdr L))))))
```

Note that in Common Lisp `(cadr nil)` returns `nil`, and this is the reason for which the error does not appear in that language.

Answer (score 4):

In Common Lisp, it is legal to take the `car` and `cdr` of `()` (aka `nil`): `(car '())` is `()` and similarly for `cdr`.  This is not the case in Scheme.  In particular, in your code, you're trying to take the `cadr` of something without first checking whether the `cdr` is `()`: you need to check for that.